# Update query for loop is not working

Tags: codeigniter, post, for-loop, sql-update

I have a query like this inside for loop in codeigniter. But it executes with another values. Not with the values getting through POST method

```
$j = $_POST['hidden'];
    $inv_id = $_POST['invoice_id'];
    $sum = '';
    for($i = 1; $i <= $j; $i++){
    $wh_quantity1 = $_POST['quantity'.$i];
    //print_r($wh_quantity1);

    if($wh_quantity1 ==''){

        $wh_quantity = 0;
    }
    else{
        $wh_quantity = $wh_quantity1;
    }
    $query = "UPDATE  tb_warehouse_stocks SET wh_product_qty = wh_product_qty - $wh_quantity WHERE invoice_id = '$inv_id'";
    $this->db->query($query);
    $sum += $wh_quantity; 

    }
```

Why it is like that. It always updates with greater values than POST value

Comment: What is the value of `wh_product_qty`?

Comment: it is there in database table. I need to update it by subtracting $wh_quantity from it

Comment: This query is vulnerable to SQL injection. Sanitize your inputs or use prepared statements to prevent horrible things from happening. Even an unintentional bit of input from a user with no ill-intentions (or his cat on the keyboard) could completely corrupt your data with this update query.

Comment: That is okay. I am not using it in live website. Do you know what is the issue here?

Comment: if invoice_id id is auto incremented value then don't use invoice_id = '$inv_id'. Just use invoice_id = $inv_id without single quote and $inv_id = (int)$_POST['invoice_id']

Comment: invoice_id is not auto incremented. It a fixed value from POST variable

Answer (score 0):

Put this in .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/international/university-english-access-course$ http://example.com/website/page/english-access [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in case your dont have all post index

```
    $j = $this->input->post('hidden');
    $inv_id = $this->input->post('invoice_id');
    $sum = 0;
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $j; $i++) {
        $wh_quantity = (int) $this->input->post('quantity' . $i);
        $sum += $wh_quantity;
    }

    $query = "UPDATE  tb_warehouse_stocks SET wh_product_qty = wh_product_qty - $sum WHERE invoice_id = '$inv_id'";
    $this->db->query($query);
```